# Computing location based on a list of approximate distances

Tags: algorithm

I have N points in at 3D space (I think I can grasp myself general N-dimensional case) and approximate distances to these points, how can I compute my position relative to these N points?

## EDIT

Please note that the distances are approximate, so the more approximate distances I have the more convenient result I should get

Thank you!

Comment: You only need 3 different points and your distance to them to find out your location -> it's the intersection point of the three circles having the r=distance to point x, and x as a center point.

Comment: The distances are approximate, so there are N equations on 3 variables X,Y,Z. But I'll appreciate the N-dimensional solution as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write down an equation that gives you some measure of the errors associated with a possible location, and then find the location that minimizes this measure. My first attempt would be to minimize the sum of the squares of the difference between the distance measured and the distance worked out from the possible location, for each of your approximate distance, so you are minimizing something like SUM_i((sqrt((X-Ai)^2 + (Y-Bi)^2 + (Z-Ci)^2) - Di)^2) where X,Y,Z is the location co-ordinates you are trying to find, (Ai,Bi,Ci) is the co-ordinates of one of the objects from which you are measuring distances, and Di is the distance measured. It doesn't look very pretty, but you should at least be able to compute derivatives and then find some sort of minimization routine in a math library.

Comment: Is the square root necessary?

Comment: I've looked through internet and found that there's a so called Least Squares Method that usually used in GPS for this kind of task, but It's not clear how to apply one to subject problem.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan The square root is necessary if you think the distance error is approximately normally distributed and you want the most accurate possible estimate. Least squares GPS look like good search terms - perhaps if you look at enough papers about this you will find one which considers trade-offs between what is easiest to compute and what gives the best accuracy. The alternatives that come to mind are so-called robust estimates which might be more accurate in some cases but which would actually be more difficult to optimise.

Answer (score 0):

You have distances from given N points in a 3D space and their approximate error values. So, you have a thick sphere for each of the points that you are in. You get all of them, calculate their intersection area, and take that area's center point as your approximate location.